# Rewrite querySelectorAll to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this little javascript to add some classes to some hyperlinks to give them a nice effect. It works on any links inside an element with the class `linkroll`. However, when the link is nested within some elements and div's, it doesnt apply the effect. I am finding that `querySelectorAll` is not very consistent.

I was thinking if I rewrite this and use something like jQuery's each() function, I may have better results. Here's how it looks now:

```
var supports3DTransforms = document.body.style['webkitPerspective'] !== undefined || document.body.style['MozPerspective'] !== undefined;
function linkify() {
    if (supports3DTransforms) {
        var selector = '.linkroll a';
        var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
            var node = nodes[i];
            var sibling = node.nextSibling; // Do not apply to images
            if (sibling.nodeName != "img") {
                if (!node.className || !node.className.match(/roll/g)) {
                    node.className += ' roll';
                    node.innerHTML = '<span data-title="' + node.text + '">' + node.innerHTML + '</span>';
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
linkify();
```

How could I possibly rewrite `document.querySelectorAll(selector);` and use something like jQuery's `each()` instead?

Comment: You said that querySelectorAll is not very consistent, which I don't agree.  Where and when your script run?  onload, ondomready, onclick or just inline code?

Comment: @John: Well, what do you think jQuery is going to use to make the DOM selection? The error in your code is likely this line: `var sibling = node.nextSibling;`, which will consider whitespace formatting after the image to be the next sibling.

Comment: -1 jQuery relies on querySelectorAll so using jQuery is not going to bring any improvement. btw I'd be curious to see a live example where querySelectorAll is not consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var supports3DTransforms = $('body').css('-webkit-perspective') !== undefined || $('body').css('MozPerspective') !== undefined;

function linkify() {
    if (supports3DTransforms) {
        $('.linkroll a').each(function (i, el) {
            var $el = $(el),
                $sibling = $el.next();
            !$sibling.is('img') && !$el.hasClass('roll') && $el.addClass('roll').wrap('<span data-title="' + $el.text() + '"></span>');
        });
    }
}

linkify();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/W28Jd/3/)

Comment: I don't want to be douche and edit the if statement in but I don't also want to encourage this either. Also the OP's code checks if the links have `.roll` class already :P

Comment: @Esailija thanks, I missed the fact the `roll` class was used to prevent the element being wrapped multiple times. I thought it was just to stop the class itself being appended multiple times. Fixed

Comment: By reading your code, it seems as if it would work, but it is not doing anything to the links.

Comment: Do you have a HTML sample you can add to your OP, or even better put in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Here it is, but I can't even get it to work at all using jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W28Jd/1/

Comment: Your fiddle didn't have the `-webkit-perspective` attribute on the body. I added a red border to the `.roll` class to make it more obvious.